# How do you echo binary data to a listening C program via netcat?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to set up a simple communication scheme with a program I wrote using UDP. The program will set up a UDP socket in a nonblocking fashion, then use select() to read non blocking from the socket. Here are the contents of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <sys/un.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>  /* Standard integer types */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int setupUdpSocketN(int *fd, uint16_t port_no)
{
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    // Create UDP socket:
    if ( (*fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0 ) 
        return -1; 
    fcntl(*fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    // Bind socket:
    memset((char *)&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no);

    if ( bind(*fd, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1 ) {
        close(*fd);
        return -2;
    }

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void) {
    int fd, maxfd, nready;
    size_t recvlen;
    uint8_t buf[256];
    fd_set rset;
    setupUdpSocketN(&fd, 60000);
    maxfd = fd + 1;

    while(1) {
        FD_ZERO(&rset);
        FD_SET(fd, &rset);

        if( (nready = select(maxfd, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0 ) {
            printf("Error in select: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        if( FD_ISSET(fd, &rset) ) {
            recvlen = recv(fd, buf, 256, 0);
            //recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, 256, 0, NULL, NULL);
            for(int i = 0; i < recvlen; i++) {
                printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I then try and send this program binary data using echo, xxd, and netcat:

```
echo -ne "\xfe\x64\x32\x1a\xb0" | xxd -rp | nc -u localhost 60000
```

However, this program when run just blocks endlessly. I'm very new to socket programming and unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is not with your code but with how you call netcat. When I run your server and use `nc -u localhost 60000`, I can reproduce your problem: The server is blocking indefinitely without receiving data. However when I force netcat to use IPv4, I can send data to the server successfully:

```
nc -4 -u localhost 60000
```

Alternatively, changing your code to use IPv6 and using netcat without the `-4` flag also works:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 my_addr;
...
if ( (*fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) 
  return -1;
...
my_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
my_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
my_addr.sin6_port = htons(port_no);
```

To show you how I debugged the problem: I first used netcat to start a UDP server, and send data to the server with a second netcat instance. This worked as expected. I then used `strace` to inspect the system calls used by the netcat server. The `strace` output shows netcat using IPv6:

```
...
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(60000), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
...
```

Besides that, there are two miscellaneous problems:

- The `recv` function returns the number of bytes received or `-1` in case of an error. For this reason, the type of the return value is `ssize_t`, instead of `size_t`. Since your code declares `size_t recvlen`, when `recv` returns `-1` an integer underflow will occur and `recv` will be the maximum possible value of type `size_t` (e.g. `ULLONG_MAX = 18446744073709551615` on my platform). This would then result in a buffer overrun, as `buf` is much smaller.
- Your `echo`/`xxd` call produces only zeros for me. I'm not sure if this intended. The `-r` flag for `xxd` enables "reverse" mode, where `xxd` will attempt to parse a hexdump (e.g. as produced by `xxd` without the `-r` flag) and then reproduces the raw byte sequence that was the input to the original hexdump. But in your case, the `echo` outputs raw binary data, not an encoded hexdump, hence this data cannot be parsed by `xxd` in reverse mode.

Comment: I figured this problem out years ago but forgot about this SO question! Thanks for revisiting and giving a thorough and correct answer!